# Como cortar una cadena en Java a partir de un caracter

Tags: java, string, netbeans, bucle-for, eclipse

mi problema es que tengo un String en Java el cual tiene varios datos de un objeto, por ejemplo:

"Q-1 Juan 200"

Quisiera una manera de quedarme solo con la parte de "Q-1" Es decir, todo lo que está antes del primer espacio.

Hice este código para detectar si el caracter es un espacio en blanco

```
for(int i=0;i<Sting.length();i++) 
{
    if(String.charAt(i)==' ') {
                                        
    }
}
```

¿Cómo hago que corte la otra parte de la cadena?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el split de strings, este te devuleve un array de string

```
string[] datos = string.split(" ");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, hice eso y tomé el string[0]